# django: how to allow post request only from forms?

Tags: django

I have a simple form:

```
{% block content %}
<p> Upload invoices </p>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'upload_thing ' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="invoice_thing">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

I have a view

```
@require_POST
@transaction.atomic
def upload_thing(request): 
      ....
```

How do I make sure that the no one can hit the post endpoint via curl or postman?

I want the end point to be accessible only by hitting the form button. The only people who can do this are admin users.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you shouldn't prevent curl or wget requests from django application. It can be done from a reverse proxy server, for example in NGINX you can put the following configuration:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (wget|curl) ) {
   return 403;
}
```

Still, its not a proper protection, `User-Agent` information can be spoofed. More information can be found in this [**`serverfault`**](https://serverfault.com/a/850776/233599) answer.

If you want to prevent people accessing this page who aren't admin, then you can simply put a restriction on the view like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
@require_POST
@transaction.atomic
def upload_thing(request): 
      if not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise PermissionDenied()
      # rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this in python is via decorators.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser)
def upload_thing(request):
```

In this way you restrict the method and not the html page.
So only logged admin can use upload_thing (from curl, postman, or html form).